# How do I change the title bar style in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, lazarus, pygubu

In the Lazarus IDE (Pascal) I can choose between title bar styles ("BorderStyle") without having to code.
Is it possible to create something similar in Pygubu-Designer, or just by adding one line of code?

[image]

Comment: Note how the button borders look like in Lazarus. They are the same like the default Windows buttons. In Tkinter we have outdated looking 2-colored frames, 2px thick. Maybe by editing the TTK theme we can achieve the same style?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you have to make the popup window yourself in tkinter. You can do it easily with a few line of codes.

For the first window style you have to use `overrideredirect` method to completely remove the header.

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk() # use toplevel if you have parent window
root.geometry("400x200")

root.overrideredirect(1)

tkinter.Label(root, text="App").pack(padx=5, anchor="w")

root.mainloop()
```

For the second one, use this code to remove the min/max button from titlebar:

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Toplevel()

root.geometry("400x200")

root.transient(root.master)
root.focus()
root.master.attributes("-alpha",0) # remove this line if you have a parent window

root.mainloop()
```

Third style is the default one, you don't have to do anything.

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk() # use toplevel if you have parent window
root.geometry("400x200")

root.mainloop()
```

For the last style, just add this line `root.attribute("-toolwindow",1)`.

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk() 
root.geometry("400x200")

root.attributes("-toolwindow",1)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this will help :)